# TCP — delivery of packets sent before client closes connection

Tags: linux, tcp

Let’s say client opens a tcp connection to server.

Say client sends 100 packets.

10 of them reached server and were picked by application.

50 of them reached server but not yet picked up by application

40 are still sitting in client
socket buffer because the servers receive window is full.

Let’s say now client closes the connection.

Question —

1. Does application get the 50 packets before it is told that the connection is closed?
2. Does the client kernel send the remaining 40 packets first to client before it sends the FIN packet?
3. Now to complicate matters, if there is lot of packet loss, what happens to the remaining 40 packets and the FIN. Does it close it?

Comment: See [The ultimate SO_LINGER page, or: why is my tcp not reliable](https://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does application get the 50 packets before it is told that the connection is closed?

It does.

> Does the client kernel send the remaining 40 packets first to client before it sends the FIN packet?

It does.

> Now to complicate matters, if there is lot of packet loss, what happens to the remaining 40 packets and the FIN. Does it close it?

The kernel will keep trying to send the outstanding data. The fact that you `close`d the socket doesn't change things, unless you altered socket options to change this behaviour.